# In Java can we create an object of a subclass in the subclass itself and outside the methods of the subclass?

Tags: java, object, subclass

I need to create an object of a subclass in the subclass itself but outside of all the methods of the subclass.

In the code below, I want to create an object of ODrawPanel at the specified location (commented part in the code) but when I do this, I get a StackOverflowError. However, I can create the object ODrawPanel inside the display() method with no problem but in that case I cannot use it in the other methods. I need to do some drawing on the panel and the panel must be available anywhere in the code.

How can I make the panel object available anywhere in the code?

Thanks for helping.

```
package odrawpanel;

import java.awt.*; 
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;

public class ODrawPanel extends JPanel
{ 
    
        private Point p1 = new Point(100, 300);
        private Point p2 = new Point(380, 300);

        // Either
        // JPanel panel = new ODrawPanel();     I want to create the object of the subclass here.
        // or
        // ODrawPanel panel = new ODrawPanel();

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
        {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);       
            g.drawLine(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y);
                        
        }
         
        public void display() 
        {   
            JPanel panel = new ODrawPanel(); 
            JFrame f = new JFrame();
 
            panel.setBounds(40, 40, 400, 400);    
            panel.setBackground(Color.white); 
            
            f.add(panel);  
            f.setSize(800,600);    
            f.setLayout(null);    
            f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            f.setVisible(true); 
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            f.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() 
            {           
                @Override
                public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) 
                {
                  panel.setSize(f.getWidth()-100,f.getHeight()-100);                                 
                }
        
            });
         
        }
        
        public static void main(String args[])  
        {          
                EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
                  {
                      @Override
                      public void run() 
                      {
                         new ODrawPanel().display();                        
                      }
                  });  
        }
        
}
```

Comment: if you initialize it when declaring it, when you create a new `ODrawPanel`, it will create a new `ODrawPanel` as an attribute, that will itself create a new `ODrawPanel`, that will also create a new `ODrawPanel`, etc. leading to a stackoverflow

Comment: "in that case I cannot use it in the other methods" - normally you'd just use `this` within the other instance methods. It's not really clear to me what you're trying to do...

Comment: side note: [Why is it frowned upon to use a null layout in Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592468/why-is-it-frowned-upon-to-use-a-null-layout-in-swing)

Comment: @JonSkeet. I want to create an object of ODrawPanel within the class ODrawPanel itself in the fields area like a global variable and then use this object in any method of ODrawPanel subclass. I am a beginner Java programmer, so please excuse me if I am asking for strange functionalities.

Comment: "like a global variable" suggests it should be a static field, which would avoid the stack overflow... but I would suggest reorganizing your code to avoid needing that at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may declare a `JPanel` supplier with lazy initialization as a field of the class:

```
private Point p1 = new Point(100, 300);
private Point p2 = new Point(380, 300);
private final Supplier<JPanel> panelSupplier = new Supplier<>() {

    private JPanel panel;

    @Override
    public JPanel get() {
        if (panel == null) {
            panel = new ODrawPanel();
        }
        return panel;
    }
};
```

... and then use it all over the class by `.get()`ting the value from the supplier (the first time you use it, the `ODrawPanel` will be created but it won't cause an overflow since you're not recursively initializing it:

```
public void display() {
    JPanel panel = panelSupplier.get(); //the first time you call get() it will create the panel, the next times it will reuse it
    JFrame f = new JFrame();

    panel.setBounds(40, 40, 400, 400);
    //...rest of the code
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create different classes for the main(), the JFrame, the JPanel.

In Main:
new JFrame();

In JFrame:
add(new JPanel());
...

In JPanel:
Do not create JPanels here.
...

Answer (score 0):

Matteo, thank you for the code. When I tried it, I got the following compiler error for the line:

```
private final Supplier<JPanel> panelSupplier = new Supplier<>()
{
   // some code here.
};
```

```
"cannot infer type arguments for Supplier<T>
  reason: '<>' with anonymous inner classes is not supported in -source 8
    (use -source 9 or higher to enable '<>' with anonymous inner classes)
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in interface Supplier"
```

After changing the code to:

```
private final Supplier<JPanel> panelSupplier = new Supplier<JPanel>()
{
  // some code here.
}
```

I did not receive an error. It works, for example, in a method like:

```
public void Test()
{
  JPanel panel = panelSupplier.get();
  panel.setBackground(Color.RED);
}
```

But it has no effect in the method:

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
{
   super.paintComponent(g);
   g.setColor(Color.BLUE);       
   g.drawLine(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y);
            
   JPanel panel = panelSupplier.get();
   panel.setBackground(Color.CYAN); 
}
```